# Spring boot latest 1.2.0.RELEASE returning ArrayStoreException while startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting following exception after upgrade to Spring boot 1.2.0.RELEASE, older version 1.0.1.RELEASE works good.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3410)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3399)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3304)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource.getManagedResource(AnnotationJmxAttributeSource.java:73)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler.includeBean(MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler.java:121)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter$1.include(MBeanExporter.java:856)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.autodetect(MBeanExporter.java:891)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.autodetectBeans(MBeanExporter.java:853)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:532)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:782)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
```

**Versions:**

java version "1.8.0_05"
Spring version: 4.1.3.RELEASE
Spring boot version 1.2.0.RELEASE
Spring security 3.2.5.RELEASE
Spring data 1.4.1.RELEASE

**POM**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>  
    <!--   <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version> - This is looking good -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring-data.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</spring-data.version>
    <start-class>com.nube.server.NubeServer</start-class>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea on this error? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like a classpath problem.

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug in Spring Boot. Can you please provide some more details? Knowing what dependencies your application has would be a big help.

Comment: Hello @AndyWilkinson Thanks for helping me. I updated with all pom dependencies. Previous version 1.0.1.RELEASE works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting the problem reported in Spring Boot [issue 2196](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2196). It'll be fixed in 1.2.1. In the meantime you could use a snapshot (available from https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot) or disable auto-configuration for Mongo:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
```